# Why does the browser sometimes return 200 (from disk cache) and 304 (from disk cache) for the same html file？

Tags: browser, browser-cache

When I refresh the page, the browser returns 304 to the html file of the website.
[image]
Then, I open a new tab, and the browser returns 200 (from disk cache) to the same html file.
[image]

I thought the browser would always return 304, or 200 (from disk cache).I want to know why the browser returns 304 and 200 (from disk cache) for the same html file in a short time.